# convergence almost surely and expected value

Tags: probability-theory

I've been getting issues with the following problem

Let $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of independent random variable such that $\mathbb{P}(X_n=1)=1/n$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_n=0)=1-1/n$. Show that 
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_n\to 0)=0 \quad \textrm{as }n \to \infty.
$$
i.e. it does not converge to zero almost surely.

I shall prove that 
$$
\mathbb{P} \left(\omega: \bigcap_{p=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{m=n}^{\infty}\left\{|X_n(\omega)|<\frac{1}{p}\right\}\right)=0
$$

My attempt is the following:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P} \left( \bigcap_{p=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{m=n}^{\infty}\left\{\omega: |X_n(\omega)|<\frac{1}{p}\right\}\right) &\leq \mathbb{P} \left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{m=n}^{\infty}\left\{\omega:|X_m(\omega)|<\frac{1}{p_0}\right\}\right)& \textrm{since }A_1 \cap A_2 \subset A_1 \\ 
&=1- \mathbb{P} \left( \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{m=n}^{\infty}\left\{\omega:|X_m(\omega)|\ge\frac{1}{p_0}\right\}\right)\\
&=1-\mathbb{P}\left( \limsup_n A_n \right)  \\
&=1-1 &\textrm{Borel-Cantelli lemma}\\
&=0.
\end{align*}
We can apply Borel-Cantelli since $\{X_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of independent random variables and 
$$
\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\mathbb{P}(A_n)=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\mathbb{P}(|X_n|\ge 1/p_0)=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\mathbb{P}(X_n=1)=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{n}=\infty.
$$

I feel like it could be shorter. You know, I'm learning and I want to write out each step.

Thanks for any suggestions/correction.

One other thing: Is it true that the $\mathbb{E}|X_n|=1/n$?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in order to disprove the almost sure convergence to $0$, you can apply the second Borel-Cantelli lemma to $A_n:=\{X_n=1\}$. This would avoid the use of $p$ and $p_0$.

Yes, it is true that $\mathbb{E}|X_n|=1/n$.

Comment: It seems I should only consider $\sum_n \mathbb{P}(X_n \neq 0)=\sum_{n} \mathbb{P}(X_n =1)=\sum_{n}\frac{1}{n}=\infty$. Moreover, since these events are independent, (as you said) by second Borel-Cantelli $\mathbb{P}(\limsup_n A_n)=1$.